# Cannot cast UITableViewCell to type

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    final let url = URL(string : "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/view-flipper/heroes.php")
    var Heroes1 = [Hero]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    //@IBOutlet weak var table: Actorcell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        downloadJson()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func downloadJson() {
        guard let downloadurl = url else{ return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadurl) { data, urlresponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlresponse != nil else{
                print("Something Wrong")
                return
            }
            //print("downloaded")
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedActor = try decoder.decode(Heroes.self, from: data)
                self.Heroes1 = downloadedActor.heroes
                print(downloadedActor)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
               print("Something Went Wrong")
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Heroes1.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:" HotelCell") as! ActorCell!
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Herocell?
        cell?.nameLbl.text = Heroes1[indexPath.row].name
        print(Heroes1[indexPath.row].name)
        if let imageURL = URL(string: Heroes1[indexPath.row].imageurl) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                if let data = data {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell?.imgLbl.image = image
                        print(image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1057a2038) to
>   'actors.Herocell' (0x1014a3f40). 2018-12-19 12:58:55.871615+0530
>   actors[3761:187113] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell'
>   (0x1057a2038) to 'actors.Herocell' (0x1014a3f40).

Thanks in advance. complete project link : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mlabuhk6mllwbzs/AADoHjZxg2e8AtQB9xfTrZMGa?dl=0

Comment: here is the full project link : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mlabuhk6mllwbzs/AADoHjZxg2e8AtQB9xfTrZMGa?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

to:

```
self.tableView.register(Herocell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Here you are saying that the cell registered with reuseIdentifier "cell" is of type `UITableViewCell` and then later in cellForRowAt, you are trying to cast it to `HeroCell`.

You need to register `HeroCell` as the type for the "cell" reuseIdentifier

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2018-12-19 13:52:54.187775+0530 actors[4668:222913] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value shows this error

Comment: What line? you are going to get these type of issues when force unwrapping everything with `!`

Comment: can you please edit my project. i will share the link so that it is very helpful. i am a beginner so i need to learn this quickly with your help....!!!    here is my project file : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mlabuhk6mllwbzs/AADoHjZxg2e8AtQB9xfTrZMGa?dl=0

Comment: If you have free time, please review my project once and make my project to work. So that i ll finish my work asap. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your project you are clearly using Prototype cells. In this case

**You must *not* register the cell in code**

Registering cells is only required if you are using an extra XIB file.

Second issue is the Module settings of the cell in IB. Keep *Inherit Module from target* checked and set Module to none.

In `cellForRow` write

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Herocell
```

This API returns always a valid cell.

And you have to return the dequeued cell rather than a generic `UITableViewCell()`

```
return cell
```

---

Note:

Loading data synchronously with `Data(contentsOf:)` in `cellForRow` – even on a background thread – is very bad programming habit. A cell can be deallocated immediately and without a cache the image is loaded again and again whenever the row is reloaded.